# Startup script causes the boot process to hang

Tags: bash

Can anyone tell me how to terminate this script properly so it does not hang the boot process? Currently its hanging on boot shortly after networking is brought up. This script was developed to control the iperf command as you would any other typical service with systemd. The file was placed in /etc/rc.d/init.d/. My system is RHEL 6.7 with a defualt run-level of 3. Judging by whats on the screen, it seems to hang right after it starts the daemon. But in the case of running at boot time I simply need this to exit after it runs the "start" command.

```
#!/bin/bash

# chkconfig: - 50 50
# description: iperf

DAEMON=/usr/bin/iperf
INFO=$(pidof /usr/bin/iperf)
IS_RUNNING=$(netstat -anp | grep ":5001" | grep "iperf" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d"/" -f 2)

case "$1" in
      start)
              $DAEMON -s -D
              ;;
      stop)
              pidof $DAEMON | xargs kill -9
              ;;
      status)

      if [ "$IS_RUNNING" = iperf ];
             then
                echo $DAEMON pid $INFO is running!!!
             else
                echo $DAEMON is NOT running!!!
              fi
              ;;
      restart)
              $DAEMON stop
              $DAEMON start
              ;;
      *)
              echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
              exit 1
              ;;
esac
exit
```

Here are my proposed changes to the script to get the behavior I want.

Add the variable:

```
S1=$(echo $?)
```

Then under the start stanza, modify as follows:

```
start)
              $DAEMON -s -D
              if [ "$S1" = 0 ];
              then
                 exit 0
              else
                 exit 2
              fi
```

Would this work?

UPDATE:

I have now got this to work without a hang at bootup. I changed this:

```
$DAEMON -s -D
```

to this:

```
nohup $DAEMON -s -D &>/dev/null &
```

This did come with an unwanted side effect however. At bootup I no longer see it scroll down the screen, its completely hidden. And once booted when I issue a "service iperf start" it hides the output and goes directly back to a prompt. Whereas before it would show me a few lines of output before returning me to the prompt. However I am satisfied with the outcome as I have been working on this for way too long.

Comment: `S1=$?` will work just as well, but I don't think that is the source of your problem. Best thing is to run the script as whatever user should run it, but with `#!/bin/bash -x` at the top, then you'll see the last cmd executed, and then you only have to figure out why it's not letting go. Hm... you probably need `$DAEMON -s -D &` ? (run it in the back-ground)? Finally, `kill -9` is a last resort, use `kill -15 $PID` (let it shut down). Good luck.

Comment: why do you have an `exit` at the very end of the script?

Comment: I updated my original question.